# Substitute for "in terms of"

Tags: word-choice

Is there a good substitute for one of the "in terms of"s in the following sentence?

> Income taxes have costs **in terms of** the welfare loss of people who pay taxes and also benefits **in terms of** tax revenue.

Can I use "as" instead of the second "in terms of"?

> Income taxes have costs **in terms of** the welfare loss of people who pay taxes and also benefits **as** tax revenue.

Comment: I would rewrite and rephrase the whole sentence.

Answer (score -3):

"in terms of" - means in relation to something

Synonyms: 
regarding, 
concerning, 
in reference to,
in connection with
thus
therein

Comment: You’re not answering the question, only addressing a more general topic.